# Juntar o comparar variables en PHP

Tags: php

tengo unas variables PHP, que son estas:

```
<?php
$on = "ON";
$off = "OFFLINE";
$disabled ="disabled";
?>
```

Bien, lo que quiero hacer es un poco mas automatico, si uso la variable "`$off`" automaticamente en otro sector se agregue la variable "`$disabled`".
Y si está en "`$on`" no ponga nada.
El "disabled" está dentrl de un "`class=""`" en una etiqueta HTML.

Y acá tendria que ir lo de Off/On
`<div id="lideres-jugador-header">
     <?php echo "$off"; ?>
 </div>`

Y aqui iria si esta disabled o no va nada:
`<a href="/link/" class="waves-effect waves-light btn <?php echo "$disabled"; ?>"> <font color="#FFFFFF">VER</font></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías colocar todo el código de lo que intentas hacer sin embargo intentare darte una respuesta con la información que das.

Primero crea variables preferiblemente que sean booleanas.

```
$switch = true; // Si es true seria el equivalente para On y false para Off
$state = true; // Si es true seria el equivalente para Enabled y false para Disabled
```

y una tercera para la salida

```
$print = "";
```

Ahora lo de los sectores no lo entiendo, sin embargo creo que lo que necesitas es un if

```
if(!$switch) 
{
    if(!$state)
    {
        $print = 'Off/Disabled';
    }

} else {
    $print = '';
}
```

Comment: Ahí edit,e, donde iria cada cosa

Comment: Que tal, estoy tratando de integrarlo, pero lo del:  `if(!$switch) 
{
    if(!$state)
    {
        $print = 'Off/Disabled';
    }

} else {
    $print = '';
}` no se como armarlo

Comment: Creo que no me sirve esto, es muy manual, yo quiero poner OFF y que automaticamente en una class, dentro de una etiqueta <a class="..." href=""></a> PONGA DISABLED y listo. Eso solo, ni mas ni menos, no que me pongo Off/Disables, por que la clase no toma eso. ¿Se entiende?

Answer (score 0):

Aun que no queda claro del todo que es lo que pretendes, creo que este puede ser uno de los casos en que se pueden aplicar variables variables de php

Ejemplo:

```
// defines los valores a mostrar
$on = "ON";
$off = "OFFLINE";
$disabled ="disabled";

// defines el estado que quieres mostrar
// debe coincidir con el nombre de alguna variable
$estado = 'on';

// muestra con variable variable
echo $$estado; // ON

// cambiamos el valor del estado
$estado = 'off';
echo $$estado; // OFFLINE
```

Nótese el uso doble de `$$` en

```
echo $$estado;
```

Documentación : http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php

*He de decir que esto puede hacer el código poco legible pudiendo derivar en caos inentendible, si no se utiliza de forma adecuada.*

Comment: No entiendo, cuando uso cada uno, $estado almacena "on" y "off"

Comment: @MatiST00 en `$estado` guardarias el nombre de la variable que quieres mostrar, al hacer `$$estado` esto mostrara la variable con con el nombre que guardes en `$estado`, por ejemlo si hacemos `$estado = 'on';`, al hacer `echo $$estado,` se resolvera como `echo $on;`. si hacemos `$estado = 'off';` el `echo $$estado,` se resolvera como `echo $off;`. Notesé el uso de `$` y `$$`

Comment: Si, ya vi lo de las dobles $$, pero entonces $$estado va a mostrar depende la variable $estado que tenga arriba? Si es así no me sirve, es mas trabajo y para eso, en html pongo OFF y en el class agrego el "disabled"

Comment: @MatiST00 Es que no queda nada claro lo que pretendes hacer realmente, ni el contexto. quizas solo necesites hacer un condicional y asignar `disable` o `" "` a la variable `$disable` pero no queda claro el motivo de porque tienes esas 3 variables y cual es su finalidad. Intenta profundizar un poco mas en tu pregunta, para darte una respuesta mas acorde. Un saludo